# How do I create a normal win32 edit control?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to create an edit control with the regular 3D border around it (in the classic windows style, anyway), but it just has a 1px black border around it. Here is my `CreateWindowEx` call:

```
return CreateWindowEx(0, "EDIT", "E:\\bk",
                      WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT,
                      87, 81, 150, 17,
                      main_window.hwnd,
                      (HMENU)5, hInstance, NULL);
```

If I exclude `WS_BORDER` then it's just a white box. Any ideas on what's wrong here?

### Update

`WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` did the trick.
I don't know anything about manifest files, or how to make the window use the more modern windows themes (XP, for example), instead of the chunky 3D borders. But, when I do learn all that, will `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` make them use those themes instead, or will it enforce the 3D look?

Comment: You will need to check which versions of comctl32.dll you are linking against, of course, But WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE will still apply. Also note that keeping up with Common Control updates is easier if you are using MFC to generate your forms. Finally, you can always use the Spy++ utility to check on the window style for a window you wish to inspect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE. That will create an inset 3-D window border under typical situations.

```
return CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "E:\\bk",
                      WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT,
                      87, 81, 150, 17,
                      main_window.hwnd,
                      (HMENU)5, hInstance, NULL);
```

Also see the following link for the rest of the available flags for CreateWindowEx.

[CreateWindowEx at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930455.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

He is right WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE will do the 3D border.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the '`WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAM`E' style.  It makes it look like the old-style 3d raised type look.  Combined with 'WS_BORDER' to make it look a like a 3d border around the control.

Answer (score 1):

Below code Creates an input box and a button, when clicked updates title.

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int main() {
  HINSTANCE hInstance;
  MSG msg;
  WNDCLASSW wc = {0};
  wc.lpszClassName = L"Edit control";
  wc.hInstance = hInstance;
  wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
  wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
  wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
  RegisterClassW(&wc);

  CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Edit control",
                WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 220, 220, 280, 200, 0, 0,
                hInstance, 0);

  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
  return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  static HWND hwndEdit;
  HWND hwndButton;
  switch (msg) {
  case WM_CREATE:

    hwndEdit = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
                             50, 50, 150, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)102, NULL, NULL);

    hwndButton = CreateWindowW(L"button", L"Set title", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                               50, 100, 80, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)103, NULL, NULL);

    break;

  case WM_COMMAND:

    if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED) {

      int len = GetWindowTextLengthW(hwndEdit) + 1;
      wchar_t text[len];

      GetWindowTextW(hwndEdit, text, len);
      SetWindowTextW(hwnd, text);
    }

    break;

  case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
  }
  return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

To compile:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.exe -mwindows
```

source: [zetcode.com/editcontrol](https://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/controls/)